# Dynamically setting the width of the buttons in Inno?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Here is my custom page definition so far:

```
var

  // Backup Settings Page & Controls
  pageAutoBackup: TWizardPage;
  btnSelectBackupFolder: TNewButton;
  textBackupFolder: TNewEdit;
  lblWhereToBackup: TLabel;
  lblPromptMode: TLabel;
  comboPromptMode: TNewComboBox;
  lblReminder: TLabel;
  radioBackupModeManual: TNewRadioButton;
  radioBackupModeAuto: TNewRadioButton;
  lblHowToBackup: TLabel;
  radioBackupHowEssential: TNewRadioButton;
  radioBackupHowComplete: TNewRadioButton;
  radioBackupHowNone: TNewRadioButton;
  lblWhatToBackup: TLabel;
  panelWhatToPackup: TPanel;
  panelHowToPackup: TPanel;

function pageAutoBackup_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
begin
    pageAutoBackup := CreateCustomPage(PreviousPageId, 'Automatic Backup', 'Configure automatic backup settings.');

    { panelWhatToPackup (TPanel) }
    panelWhatToPackup := TPanel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    panelWhatToPackup.Caption := '';
    panelWhatToPackup.BevelOuter := bvNone;
    panelWhatToPackup.BevelInner := bvNone; { default }
    panelWhatToPackup.BevelKind := bkNone;
    panelWhatToPackup.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    panelWhatToPackup.Enabled := True;
    panelWhatToPackup.Visible := True;
    panelWhatToPackup.Left := ScaleX(0);
    panelWhatToPackup.Top := ScaleY(0);
    panelWhatToPackup.Width := pageAutoBackup.Surface.Width;
    panelWhatToPackup.Height := ScaleY(90);
    panelWhatToPackup.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight];

    { lblWhatToBackup (TLabel) }
    lblWhatToBackup := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblWhatToBackup.Parent := panelWhatToPackup;
    lblWhatToBackup.Enabled := True;
    lblWhatToBackup.Visible := True;
    lblWhatToBackup.Width := panelWhatToPackup.Width;
    lblWhatToBackup.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblWhatToBackup.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblWhatToBackup.Caption := 'What to backup:';

    { radioBackupHowNone (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupHowNone := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupHowNone.Parent := panelWhatToPackup;
    radioBackupHowNone.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupHowNone.Visible := True;
    radioBackupHowNone.Top := lblWhatToBackup.Top + lblWhatToBackup.Height + ScaleY(2);
    radioBackupHowNone.Width := panelWhatToPackup.Width;
    radioBackupHowNone.Checked := False;
    radioBackupHowNone.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupHowNone.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupHowNone.Caption := 'Don''t perform any backup when the program shuts down';

    { radioBackupHowComplete (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupHowComplete := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupHowComplete.Parent := panelWhatToPackup;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Visible := True;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Top := radioBackupHowNone.Top + radioBackupHowNone.Height + ScaleY(2);
    radioBackupHowComplete.Width := panelWhatToPackup.Width;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Checked := False;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Caption := 'Make a complete backup when the program shuts down';

    { radioBackupHowEssential (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupHowEssential := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupHowEssential.Parent := panelWhatToPackup;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Visible := True;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Top :=  radioBackupHowComplete.Top + radioBackupHowComplete.Height + ScaleY(2);
    radioBackupHowEssential.Width := panelWhatToPackup.Width;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Checked := False;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Caption := 'Only make an essential backup when the program shuts down';

    { panelHowToPackup (TPanel) }
    panelHowToPackup := TPanel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    panelHowToPackup.Caption := '';
    panelHowToPackup.BevelOuter := bvNone;
    panelHowToPackup.BevelInner := bvNone; { default }
    panelHowToPackup.BevelKind := bkNone;
    panelHowToPackup.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    panelHowToPackup.Enabled := True;
    panelHowToPackup.Visible := True;
    panelHowToPackup.Top := panelWhatToPackup.Top + panelWhatToPackup.Height + ScaleY(2);
    panelHowToPackup.Width := pageAutoBackup.Surface.Width;
    panelHowToPackup.Height := ScaleY(100);
    panelHowToPackup.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight];

    { lblHowToBackup (TLabel) }
    lblHowToBackup := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblHowToBackup.Parent := panelHowToPackup;
    lblHowToBackup.Enabled := True;
    lblHowToBackup.Visible := True;
    lblHowToBackup.Width := panelHowToPackup.Width;
    lblHowToBackup.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblHowToBackup.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblHowToBackup.Caption := 'How to backup:';

    { radioBackupModeAuto (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupModeAuto := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupModeAuto.Parent := panelHowToPackup;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Visible := True;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Left := ScaleX(0);
    radioBackupModeAuto.Top := lblHowToBackup.Top + lblHowToBackup.Height + ScaleY(2);
    radioBackupModeAuto.Width := panelHowToPackup.Width;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Checked := False;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Caption := 'Perform automatically when the program is shut down';

    { radioBackupModeManual (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupModeManual := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupModeManual.Parent := panelHowToPackup;
    radioBackupModeManual.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupModeManual.Visible := True;
    radioBackupModeManual.Top := radioBackupModeAuto.Top + radioBackupModeAuto.Height + ScaleY(2);
    radioBackupModeManual.Width := panelHowToPackup.Width;
    radioBackupModeManual.Checked := False;
    radioBackupModeManual.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupModeManual.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupModeManual.Caption := 'Prompt the user when the program is shut down';

    { lblPromptMode (TLabel) }
    lblPromptMode := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblPromptMode.Parent := panelHowToPackup;
    lblPromptMode.Enabled := True;
    lblPromptMode.Visible := True;
    lblPromptMode.Top := radioBackupModeManual.Top + radioBackupModeManual.Height + ScaleY(2);
    lblPromptMode.Width := panelHowToPackup.Width;
    lblPromptMode.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblPromptMode.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblPromptMode.Caption := 'Also prompt to backup at the following intervals while the application is running:';

    { comboPromptMode (TNewComboBox) }
    comboPromptMode := TNewComboBox.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    comboPromptMode.Parent := panelHowToPackup;
    comboPromptMode.Style := csDropDownList;
    comboPromptMode.Enabled := True;
    comboPromptMode.Visible := True;
    comboPromptMode.Top := lblPromptMode.Top + lblPromptMode.Height + ScaleY(2);
    comboPromptMode.Width := panelHowToPackup.Width;
    comboPromptMode.Font.Color := $000000;
    comboPromptMode.ItemIndex := 0;
    comboPromptMode.Color := $FFFFFF;
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('Never prompt to backup');
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('Prompt to backup everyday');
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('Prompt to backup once a week');
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('Prompt to backup once a month');
    comboPromptMode.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight];

    { lblWhereToBackup (TLabel) }
    lblWhereToBackup := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblWhereToBackup.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    lblWhereToBackup.Enabled := True;
    lblWhereToBackup.Visible := True;
    lblWhereToBackup.Top := panelHowToPackup.Top + panelHowToPackup.Height + ScaleY(2);
    lblWhereToBackup.Width := panelHowToPackup.Width;
    lblWhereToBackup.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblWhereToBackup.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblWhereToBackup.Caption := 'Where to backup:';
    lblWhereToBackup.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];

    { textBackupFolder (TNewEdit) }
    textBackupFolder := TNewEdit.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    textBackupFolder.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    textBackupFolder.Enabled := True;
    textBackupFolder.Visible := True;
    textBackupFolder.Top := lblWhereToBackup.Top + lblWhereToBackup.Height + ScaleY(2);
    textBackupFolder.Width := ScaleX(335);
    textBackupFolder.Font.Color := $000000;
    textBackupFolder.Color := $F0F0F0;
    textBackupFolder.Anchors := [akLeft, akRight, akBottom];

    { btnSelectBackupFolder (TNewButton) }
    btnSelectBackupFolder := TNewButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Enabled := True;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Visible := True;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Left := ScaleX(340);
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Top := textBackupFolder.Top;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Width := ScaleX(75);
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Caption := 'Browse ...';
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Anchors := [akRight, akBottom];
    btnSelectBackupFolder.OnClick := @btnSelectBackupFolder_Click;

    Result := pageAutoBackup.ID;

end;
```

This is what it looks like at smallest size possible:

[image: Smallest Size]

Due to limited space I decided to remove one of the static labels as it was not really needed.

This is what it looks like when resized:

[image: Bigger Size]

It is looking good. My queries relate to some specific sizes of controls:

Since I will be localising the page I can't assume the specified widths for the "Browse ..." button. How do we set it so that this button is over on the right, taking whatever width is required for the eventual custom message and the text control be sized accordingly on the left of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that it is common in Windows to adjust a size of controls according to their caption text. Just make the button large enough to fit all the translations. Imo, the general rule is to add 50% on top of original English text for controls with long captions and 100% to controls with short captions (like yours).

Or, as your button is one-word as other standard Inno Setup buttons, you can use the same width for consistency.

```pascal
btnSelectBackupFolder.Width := WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
```

---

If you really want to autosize, there no straightforward way to calculate the caption width as Inno Setup does not expose a control's canvas.

You can hack it by either:

- Creating a temporary [`TLabel`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TLabel) with `AutoSize := True`, set the caption and query the label width.
- Creating a temporary [`TBitmapImage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TBitmapImage) and use its `TBitmapImage.Bitmap.Canvas.TextWidth` to calculate text width.

In both cases make sure the control's `Font` and parent matches the button's font and parent. To remove the temporary control, call its `.Free` method.